# Start any android application from broadcast receiver without delay

Tags: android, performance, broadcastreceiver

my application catches calls in background using broadcast receiver and after that the app is launched. But the launch has a serious delay (20-30 seconds on Android 4.1.2). How can I speed up the app launch?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

 if(!mLastState.equals(phoneState)){
     switch (phoneState){
        case("RINGING"):
            mLastState="RINGING";
            try {
             Intent i =context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com....");
             context.startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO
            }
            break;
        case("OFFHOOK"):
            mLastState="OFFHOOK";
            break;
        case("IDLE"):
            mLastState="IDLE";
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
    }
}`
```

Comment: I think it's due to your main launcher activity for which you did not provide code.  Are you doing a lot on the Main UI thread when you launch?

Comment: The only delay that's enforced for launching activities is a 5 second delay after pressing the home button, so 20-30s means you must be doing something very wrong. Posting more relevant code will help someone point out what that is exactly.

Comment: It’s difficult to show all code because I have some abstract classes and multiple inheritance. Due to your help I checked my app again and understood that the problem is not here.
BUT  
I launch the app from the broadcast receiver class is it correct or not? And if I need to read big data when phone call starts and then to show the app + data when phone call stops. How to handle the action correctly? 
Note the data can be read faster than phone call stops (and I need somewhere to temporarily store the data)  and vice versa phone call stops faster than the app read the data.

Comment: @Delphian Do you solve this isssue